# Как настроить совместимость проекта vue.js для IE 11?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babel, ie11

Помогите настроить совместимость проекта vue.js для IE 11.
[image: Вот такие ошибки в консоли]

Вот такие ошибки в консоли. Установил и подключил @babel/polyfill в main.js, не помогает.Что может быть не так в строчке: eval("**webpack_require**.r(**webpack_exports**); ?

Comment: ES5 совместимость нужна. это пробуй для своего babelrc: {
  "presets": [
    [
      "@vue/app",
      {
        "targets": {
          "ie": "11"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: У меня нет файла babelrc, есть babel.config.js. Это одно и то же? Если нет , как я могу найти файл .babelrc?

Comment: посмотрте тут https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targets

Comment: npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev и настройте совместимость с вашим браузером

Comment: А открыть проект в dev-режиме через IE11 - не пробовали? Там бы более конкретно ошибка была указана. Зачастую - нужно просто const на var поменять

Comment: Я и открыл через dev режим. Мне бы узнать какой в вэбпаке devtool указан..чтобы поменять eval на none